# Why am I getting std::bad_alloc when I have so much free memory available

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, operating-system

One of my processes is restarting over and over apparently because of following messages in log file:

```
Wed Jun 13 10:07:32 2012: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Wed Jun 13 10:07:32 2012:   what():  St9bad_alloc
```

I understand that this is because it is not being able to allocate memory to 'new' request. What I don't understand is that 'free -m' tells me that lot of free memory is available discarding caches:

-bash-3.00$ free -m

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:         32175      32113         61          0        412      24021

-/+ buffers/cache:       7679      24495

Swap:        12287          0      12287
```

Is it cribbing because free memory (with current caching) is very less, but I would guess that to cater to 'new' request, this caching can be released. Or do I need to switch on something to force release of cache or something else is going wrong here?

Comment: Do you know how much memory you try to allocate?

Comment: Can you debug it? Break on throwing the exception and check what the values are. It might be that you are asking for too much memory (say 10Gb) or too little (a negative value). Both of them can fail with `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: While I try to debug it and find out more information, one thing which might be useful to mention here is that my system works on a config file which has list of similar things to process. Uptil a good number of items, the system works fine. It is only when I add after this threshold that this error starts happening. So I would think that there is nothing wrong with basic correctness of code such as trying to allocate -ve memory or randomly huge memory etc etc. This is only a guess though.

Comment: When did you run `free -m`? Unless you ran it slightly before `Wed Jun 13 10:07:32 2012`, it doesn't tell you how much memory was free at the time the allocation failed. Maybe your app has a massive memory leak, all of which is of course freed when it terminates. It would work fine until you run out of memory, then throw the exception.

Comment: I use sar command to check history of free memory available and buffers cached and they are like 24 GB (Total RAM is 32 GB)..In such case, it's difficult to understand why OS can't release this cache to cater to 'new' request (and also given that I run into this problem when I add one more item to process -- Pls read my earlier comment)

Comment: Note that it's also possible (given a buggy C++ program) for the process's heap to get corrupted in such a way that the heap-allocator routine fails even though there is still RAM physically available to use (e.g. because a pointer in one of the heap's data structures got erroneously overwritten with zeros).  Running the program under valgrind to check for heap corruption might not be a bad idea, if all else fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be few reasons, a good place to start is with knowing how much memory you are requesting.

I can think of two reason for this to happen which are, an allocation of negative size or a to big size (more than 4GB of 32bit machine). or a fragmentation problem (which can happen after a lot allocation-free calls but it's not that common.)

To see memory fragmentation you can use the magic SysRq key. Simply execute the following command:

echo m > /proc/sysrq-trigger
This command will dump current memory information to /var/log/messages. Here is an example of a RHEL3 32-bit system:

> Jul 23 20:19:30 localhost kernel: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB 0*64kB
>   1*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 1952kB)

==EDIT==
how to read the results: when the system is going up it split the memory into 4Mb (4096Kb) chunks of continuous memory. when ever your system allocate memory those chunks are been split up to smaller size and the OS will allocate the closest power of two memory chunk.

So "1*1024kB" mean you have a piece of 1 Mb continuous memory in the system.

In case like: "4*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB" although you do have 4Mb free, there are split into 4 1Mb chunks. if you would request the OS for 1 allocation of 4 Mb it will fail cause 1 allocation must return a continuous memory.

I hope any of this make sense to you (-;

Comment: +1 on starting with how much memory is being requested. Fragmentation would not show the memory as *free* (or *cached*), as it is memory that is allocated to the application even if not to any particular object.

Comment: I have a RHEL 5.6 64 bit machine and echo m > /proc/sysrq-trigger does not leave any output in /var/log/messages. Any clue?

Comment: And also how to make sense of the output you give? What does 1*512kB and 0*4kB mean?

Comment: For this you'll need to learn about the memory management of the OS. I'll edit the answer with a high level explanation...

Comment: @Roee Gavirel - I think you meant `chunks` not `chanks`